# iOS notification when connection is back

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, push-notification, messaging

I'm developing a queue of messages for a messenger app. 
On Android if the connection is lost, messages is save on the queue and as soon as the 3G or wifi is back the messages go out of the queue. This is possible thanks I'm listening a broadcast receiver which alert me when the connection is back.

Is there anything similar on iOS?
Any workaround on iOS to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: Note that in general, iOS push notifications don't have guaranteed deliverability.

Comment: My questions is related to be able to send a message to a server as soon as the internet connection is back. I need a mechanism to alert my app the connection is back to send a message in background.

Answer (score 0):

You determine the restoration of an internet connection via the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) class. You can attempt resending once Reachability tells you that you have an Internet connection again.

Comment: I don't believe so, at least not when the app has entered suspended [state](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html). Apple only allows a narrow set of apps (voip, music players, gps, etc.) to stay active in the background.